# GUI trouble in java - Hangman

Tags: java

Im trying to make a hangman game in java using JPanels and labels, but I am struggling to get all of my panels showing up.  I have to make a drawing of the hangman in a panel below the text field, but when I run my code the text field takes up the entire GUI and doesn't show my drawing at all. If anyone can help that would be great. Heres my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;


public class GameMaker extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel wordLabel = new JLabel("Word to Guess");
    private JTextField text = new JTextField(5);
    private JPanel wordPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel renameThisField;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private String[] guesses = {"Brendan", "Vaughn", "Josh"};
    private char[] randomWordToGuess = 
guesses[random.nextInt(guesses.length)].toCharArray();
    private int amountOfGuesses = randomWordToGuess.length;
    private char[] playerGuess = new char[amountOfGuesses];
    private Graphics g;

    public GameMaker(){
        createComponents();
    }

    public void createComponents(){
        boolean wordIsGuessed = false;
        int tries = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<playerGuess.length; i++){
            playerGuess[i] = ' ';
            printArray(playerGuess);
        }

        JLabel wordToGuessLabelBlank = new JLabel("_ _ _ _ _ _ _");
        button = new JButton("Submit Letter");
        ActionListener listener = new SubmitLetter();
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        button1 = new JButton("adasdasd");
        ActionListener listener1 = new SubmitLetter();
        button1.addActionListener(listener1);
        label = new JLabel();

        JLabel wordLength = new JLabel("The word to Guess is " + playerGuess.toString() + 
"letters long.");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 1;
        final JTextField rateField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.add(wordLabel);
        panel.add(wordToGuessLabelBlank);
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        panel.add(wordLength);
        panel.add(rateField);
        JComponent component = new BodyComponent();
        panel.add(component);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        add(panel);

    }
    public void printArray(char[] array){
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public class SubmitLetter implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){


        }

        /*This is where the magic happens.
         * increment the numClicks and display results
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: This code is incomplete.  Do you have the driver code that creates a `GameMaker` and displays the window?  That would help a lot.  Also the code for `BodyComponent` is not shown, either include it or remove that line from the MCVE.

Comment: The code above seems to display OK, after I add a driver class and remove a few lines that can't be resolved.  You'll have to do some work and post a [mcve] for us, and be specific when you describe what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Why are you are calling `panel.setLayout()` twice.?